# Meaning of congruence as defined in Apostol's Calculus

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry

While defining area axiomatically, Apostol makes the statement following statement:

> The term "rectangle" as used here refers to any set congruent to a set of the form $$\{ (x,y)|0\le x\le h\ ,\ 0\le y\le k \}$$

with congruence defined in the footnotes as follows:

> Two sets are said to be congruent if their points can be put in one-to-one correspondence in such a way that distances are preserved. That is, if two points $p$ and $q$ in one set correspond to $p'$ and $q'$ in the other, the distance from $p$ to $q$ must be equal to the distance from $p'$ to $q'$; this must be true for all choices of $p$ and $q$.

What exactly does he mean by "correspond" here? Obviously, I have an intuitive idea of what he's trying to get at here but I can't figure out what a pair of points in the two sets corresponding with each other means precisely.

Answer (score 2):

The correspondence is usually called an *isometry* (or *congruence*). It's a one-to-one and onto transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (a *bijection* from the plane to itself). This means that the transformation has an inverse as well, which you can show is also an isometry.

The correspondence is between a point $(x_0, y_0)$ and its image under this transformation, say
$$
(u_0, v_0) = T(x_0, y_0).
$$

The distance preserving condition can be written as
$$
d\bigl( (u_0, v_0),\, (u_1, v_1) \bigr)
= d\bigl( (x_0, y_0),\, (x_1, y_1) \bigr)
$$

These isometric transformations fall into a few familiar families:

- Translations
- Rotations
- Reflections
- Glide reflections

which you can read much more about [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Euclidean_plane_isometry).

Comment: Could you explain why the domain of the transformation $T$ is the entire plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ rather than just the figure?

Comment: The domain has to at least include the figure, but for many common transformations, we can define the transformation on the entire plane. The entire plane is shifted, rotated, flipped, etc. and the particular rectangle you're interested moves from one place to another.